# Powershell JSON to CSV Conversion and Export

Tags: json, excel, powershell, csv

I have the following JSON file (example output from a Invoke-RestMethod call) https://filebin.net/t3dtujxnssr6dcic/0.json?t=j2lr5rnb . I am trying to run a Powershell command to export this to CSV but keep encountering errors resulting in the CSV being empty or just one line showing SystemObject.

I know the headers for the CSV columns should be: noticeId,title,solicitationNumber,department,subTier,office,postedDate,type,baseType,archiveType,archiveDate,typeOfSetAsideDescription,typeOfSetAside,responseDeadLine,naicsCode,classificationCode,active,award,pointOfContact,description,organizationType,officeAddress,placeOfPerformance,additionalInfoLink,uiLink,links/0,resourceLinks

my command is:

```
((Get-Content -Path $getpath) | ConvertFrom-Json).results | Export-CSV -Path $topath -NoTypeInformation
```

I end up getting the following error:

```
Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:1 char:61
+ ... nvertFrom-Json).results | Export-CSV -Path $topath -NoTypeInformation
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCo
   mmand
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the output of `((Get-Content -Path $getpath) | ConvertFrom-Json).results`? it appears to be empty based on the error

Comment: Where does your ```.results``` come from? From your data file it looks like you should be using ```.opportunitiesData``` instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the guys mentioned in the comments it looks like you're trying to retrieve the data stored in the JSON file under the field "opportunitiesData".

The solution is as simple as changing `.results` to `.opportunitiesData`

Your line should be:

```
((Get-Content -Path $getpath) | ConvertFrom-Json).opportunitiesData | Export-CSV -Path $topath -NoTypeInformation
```